# sandboxing approaches

Tags: sandbox

do you know where to find another comparison between sandboxing approaches like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization#Implementations)?

Also, I'd like you guys to explain to me why isn't SELinux or Seccomp included in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why isn't SELinux or Seccomp included in that table

As it says at the top of that page, it regards:

> **Operating system-level virtualization** [...] where the kernel of an operating system allows for multiple isolated user-space instances

That's not what SELinux or Seccomp do.  They restrict what a process can do in *the existing* user space, as opposed to creating *a seperate* user space for processes to operate within.  [Virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) can also be used for sandboxing, and they are not in that list either, since while they generally would isolate a user-space, they also isolate kernel space.  So, a virtual machine can sandbox an entire operating system, OS level virtualization just sandboxes the user space, and things like SELinux just sandbox individual processes or users.

Here's a few of the things that are separated in "a separate user space":

- Filesystems: Meaning, you can't access *any* of the files in the host space.  SELinux, by contrast, just restricts which files can be accessed.  Part of the significance of this is that it includes libraries, executables, etc.  You can sandbox an application and run it using SELinux, but in an OS level virtualization context, you'd have to install and run the application in the container first.  You cannot not run *anything* from the host OS.
- Networking: Meaning, if you need to access a network, that access must be arranged separately within the container.  You cannot use the networking connections of the host OS.